# how to redirect to https based on source IP?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, rewrite

I have a website running `apache` which is accessed

- internally (rfc1918 address space) as either `http://hostname` or `http://hostname.local`
- externally (public address space) as https://example.org.

How can I redirect access when internal users access from 10.0.1.0/24 address space any page on `http://hostname/*` or `http://hostname.local/*` so they are sent to the relevant page on `https://hostname.example.org`

Caveat being I have two subnets 10.0.1.0/24 which I'd like to do `https` and 10.0.2.0/24 which I **do not** want to do https at the moment

What I have at the moment is

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 10\.0\.1 
RewriteRule .* https://hostname.example.org/ [R=301,L]
```

But I do not know how to make it so the user gets sent to `https://hostname.example.org/test` if they go to `http://hostname[.local]/test`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hostname.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it so that only hits to hostname.local go to there you add the condition HTTP_HOST below and adjust the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 10\.0\.1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hostname\.local$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hostname.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```